# Invoke a program as a command on any working directory on ubuntu's terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I have written a program in C and produced an executable from it. I want to use this program from any `pwd`. One method is to make its pathname a environment variable using `export`. But in this method, everytime I want to invoke my program, I need to prefix my command word with `$`. I want my command to work like in-build commands like `cat`, `grep`, `awk`, `top`, `man`, etc.

Let's say my command is `myprog`.

```
$ myprog arg1 arg2
```

this command should invoke my executable from any directory as the `pwd` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your program into your $HOME/bin directory. Next login your $PATH should contain your bin dir, so the program should work as you described.

Comment: To be sure, after you `cp myprog ~/bin`, type `rehash` to force the shell to rescan the directories in `$PATH`.